# Change directory with space followed by '('

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

There are two directories I can change to:

```
Program Files/       Program Files (x86)/
```

I can change to first one by writing:

```
cd Program\ Files
```

But the second for second one:

```
cd Program\ Files\ (x86)
```

I get:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What is the right way to change to second directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to escape the parentheses:

```
cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)
```

Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> will usually complete the command line for you, and will give hints how to quote the file/directory names.

Comment: Yes, Tab completes, but I have two directories with the same name till (x86) so it only completes to "Program Files".

Comment: @enedene That's right, although afterwards you can type `\ ` and take advantage of completion.

Comment: An alternative that may be useful in this case is to use shell globbing. For example, `cd P` TAB `??x86?` TAB will likely (depending on what else you have in the relevant directory) complete out to `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: At some point backslashes become more of a problem than they're worth.  If you have more than one or two special characters it's simpler to quote the entire file name; either `"Program Files (x86)"` or `'Program Files (x86)'` will work.

Comment: Hitting TAB multiple times should cycle through the available matches.  `cd Prog` TAB TAB.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish the same is to quote the path containing whitespace:

```
cd "Program Files (x86)"
```

This also works with tab-completion so you can type:

```
cd "Program<Space><Tab><Space><Tab>
```

Notice the opening double-quote. Then you will get:

```
cd "Program Files (x86)"/
```